# Laravel Sanctum & broadcasting with Pusher.js (401, 419 error)

Tags: laravel, laravel-echo, laravel-sanctum, pusher-js, nuxt-auth

For 4 days I have been trying to connect to a private channel. Combined all the possible properties that I could find, but nothing solved the problem. A deeper understanding of the issue is needed.

I am creating an application using Laravel Sanctum, Nuxt.js, Nuxt-auth.
I need to connect to a broadcasting private channel.

At first I tried to create a connection using the [@nuxtjs/laravel-echo](https://github.com/nuxt-community/laravel-echo-module) package.
After long attempts to configure the connection, I found that the PisherConnector instance is not even created if I set the `authModule: true` (Public channels connect perfectly). Having discovered that this package is not actively supported and the fact that I do not have full access to connection management, I decided to abandon it.

Then I tried to set a connection using Laravel-echo and then directly through Pusher. Nothing works, I get either a 401 or 419 error.

I have a lot of questions and no answers.

1. When do I need to use [laravel-echo-server](https://github.com/tlaverdure/laravel-echo-server)?
2. When do I need to use [pusher/pusher-php-server](https://github.com/pusher/pusher-http-php)?
3. In which case do I need to connect to `broadcasting/auth`, and in which to `api/broadcasting/auth`? My frontend runs on `api/login`, but I don't want to provide external access to my API.
4. I added `Broadcast::routes(['middleware' => ['auth: sanctum']])` to my `BroadcastServiceProvider` and to `routes/api.php` too (for testing). I'm not sure here either. `Broadcast::routes(['middleware' => ['auth: api']])` may be needed or leave the default `Broadcast::routes()`?
5. What are the correct settings for configs: `config/cors.php`, `config/broadcasting.php`, `config/sanctum.php`, `config/auth.php`? What key parameters can affect request validation?
6. Should I pass CSRF-TOKEN to headers? I have tried in different ways.
7. When do I need to set the `encrypted:true` option?
8. What `middleware` should be present in the `Kernel` and what might get in the way?

If I set `authEndpoint` to `api/broadcasting/auth` I get 419 error (trying to pass csrf-token does not help). If I set `authEndpoint` to `broadcasting/auth` I get 401 error.

I do not provide examples of my code, since I tried all the options in all configs. I also tried to learn the documentation for my issue on the Laravel site, Pusher.js, looked at examples. Various examples mention some options but not others, and vice versa.

I would be glad to any advice.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue as you. I had forgot to add the `BroadCastingServiceProvider` in my `/config/app.php`.

The `app/Providers/BroadcastServiceProvider.php` now looks like this:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Broadcast;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class BroadcastServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        Broadcast::routes(['middleware' => ['api', 'auth:sanctum']]);
        require base_path('routes/channels.php');
    }
}
```

I have not added `Broadcast::routes` to any other route file.

This is what my Laravel Echo init looks like:

```js
new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: 'korvrolf',
    wsHost: window.location.hostname, // I host my own web socket server atm
    wsPort: 6001, // I host my own web socket server atm
    forceTLS: false,
    auth: {
        withCredentials: true,
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': window.Laravel.csrfToken
        }
    }
})
```

Without the CSRF-token the endpoint will return the `419` status response.

In my `index.blade.php` for my SPA I print out the CSRF-token:

```html
<script>
    window.Larvel = {
        csrfToken: "{{ csrf_token() }}"
    }
</script>
```

Now, the `/broadcast/auth` endpoint returns a 200 response.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with Laravel & pusher.
I have fixed using `decodeURIComponent` and moving `BroadCast::routes(['middleware' => ['auth:sanctum']])` to `routes/api.php` from `BroadcastServiceProvider.php`

Also, add `withCredentials = true`.

```
const value = `; ${document.cookie}`
const parts = value.split(`; XSRF-TOKEN=`)
const xsrfToken = parts.pop().split(';').shift()
Pusher.Runtime.createXHR = function () {
                    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
                    xhr.withCredentials = true
                    return xhr
                }
const pusher = new Pusher(`${process.env.REACT_APP_PUSHER_APP_KEY}`,
                    {
                        cluster: 'us3',
                        authEndpoint: `${process.env.REACT_APP_ORIG_URL}/grooming/broadcasting/auth`,
                        auth: {
                            headers: {
                                Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
                                'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
                                'X-XSRF-TOKEN': decodeURIComponent(xsrfToken)
                            }
                        }
                    })
```

I hope this helps a bit.